# UITableview edit option networking when reloaded in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview, ios8

I am working on iOS 8-beta with Xcode 6-beta.Making iOS 7 application compatible for iOS 8.On "Edit" button click i am setting the UITableview to edit mode and it works fine.But when reload data in edit mode,then the "-" red button disappears but the tableview is still in edit mode.Could anyone help me out.I know its the beta version and bugs are expected but   if its something i messed up then.Thank You.

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```